# NullPointerException on setVisibility function in FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have developed android project and published to a google playstore.
In this app, for tab use, at one activity, calling frameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) for showing other layouts.
It is working perfectly on my android devices.

But when i check crashlytics, i can see applications crashed on that function.

I tried many google searches but i did not found the solution and did not fix yet.

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Post your activity/fragment source code.

Comment: And error log also

Comment: This would be a great time to get some nice error logging setup.  Assuming the error is real, you need to try to reproduce it locally.  Perhaps there are some use cases which you never tested or thought of.

Comment: I have checked but not duplicated case. I have already tried almost nullpointerexception cases in stackoverflow. But it did not help me. I hope anyone can explain me which cases in android cause this error. On my android devices, i did not see this error yet.

Comment: It has probably something to do with Actiity/Fragment lifecycles. Check if the object is guaranteed to be created when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without any code snippets will be hard to realise, but since is a NPE error I am guessing that your layout is not a valid one or the fragment it was in, has been changed.